# How to create a module that shows some fields of profile2 type?

Tags: 7, theming, entities, hooks

I want to create a module that shows some fields of [profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) type, in fact I want to show some information about any user in profile page of theme.
Profile2 type is "stores", field machine name is "field_store_name" and my module name is "profile_header".
I put below code in profile_header.module

```
 <?php  
function profile_header_block_info() {
  return array(
    'profile_header' => array(
      'info' => 'profile stores header',
      'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE
    )
  );
}

function profile_header_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();

    global $user;
    $account = user_load($user->uid);
    $user_fields = user_load($uid);
    $profile = profile2_load_by_user($account, $stores = NULL);
    $field_store_name = field_get_items('profile2', $profile2['stores'], 'field_store_name'); 
    $block['subject'] = 'profile stores header ';
    $block['content'] =  theme(
          'profile_header',
          array(
            'field_store_name' => $field_store_name,               
          )
        );   
     return $block;      
}

function profile_header_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'profile_header' => array(
      'template' => 'profile_header',
      'path' => $path . '/theme',
      'variable' => array(
        'user_fields' => NULL,   
      ),
    ),

  );
}
```

and put below code in profile_header.tpl.php, and clearly I put this file in `profile_header/theme` directory.

```
<?php
?>

<section class="container"> 
    <aside class="store-bio">
        <div class="store-name">
            <?php print $field_store_name ; ?>
        </div>
    </aside>
 </section>
```

But unfortunately this module doesn't show anything.

Comment: You can easily do this with Views in less than 1 min, but ok...

Comment: I know, but if you can solve this problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your [`hook_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7.x) implementation is returning an array with missing details; the key should be `variables` and its value array should contain keys that matches the variable names in your template.

```
function profile_header_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'profile_header' => array(
      'template' => 'profile_header',
      'path' => $path . '/theme',
      'variables' => array(
        'field_store_name' => NULL,   
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```